# Perfect Assistant - Error in Importing Existing Package

Tags: perfect

Version: Perfect Assistant v 3.0.5
Swift: 4.1.2
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0

I cloned, built and ran the `PerfectTemplate` package. Everything runs perfectly (pun intended).  I have not (yet) created the `Xcode` project for this package.

When I try and import this package into Perfect Assistant, it's telling me the package is not a valid SPM (see screen shot):

[image: Perfect Assistant Project Details]

I'm not sure what's going on here and I'm stuck. I can attached the `Package.swift` file if needed, but I haven't changed anything from the clone and it builds and runs fine from the command line.

Can anyone share what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
// Generated automatically by Perfect Assistant Application
// Date: 2017-09-20 19:30:47 +0000
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(
    name: "PerfectTemplate",
    targets: [],
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", majorVersion: 3),
    ]
)
```

Comment: hey! I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Same issue here. It looks like Perfect Assistant has been discontinued. The last Swift supported is 4.2.1!!!